# Clear JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am using this to read JSON in PHP

```
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

What I need after that is a way to clear the JSON since I am sending new content back to JavaScript.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're actually trying to accomplish. You're using PHP to grab raw JSON-encoded data, and then you're trying to pass it to a JavaScript variable? Can you not just use AJAX? Also, what exactly do you mean by you need to "*clear*" the JSON? Are you attempting to overwrite it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"clear the JSON"*? What is the outcome you want to achieve?

Comment: Obsidian - Correct. An overwrite would also work. However, my debugging reveals that the JSON string is not overwritten but rather appended.

Answer (score -2):

you forgot

$str_json = file_get_contents('/my_file.json');

`$data = json_decode($str_json, true);`

//if you have only one object inside your data

`$data['index_name'];`

//if your data is JSON arrayObject

`foreach($data as $i ){`

`$i['index_name'];`

`}`

Comment: I have that in the code. Jus did not copy it here. What I am after is to be able to clear or delete whatever is in the JSON object. Maybe even delete the object completely. So far have not been able to achieve any of that.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: adding true to the json_decode doesn't fix the problem , can you explain why you just post this answer !!?

Comment: you can just retrieve your object from $data

Comment: ok i've put the first part of your code on my answer this maybe help you see the hole picture